# Angular 2 background image webpack 2

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I try to add some bg-image at my html template, but it isn't render. I searched for solution im internet, webpack and angular docs, but coudn't find a right solution.

my webpack config use file loader for images:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader', 
                'angular2-template-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap'})
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader'
        }
    ]
},
```

and my template looks like:

```
<div class="hero" 
     [ngStyle]="{'background-image':url(../../assets/img/1.jpg)'}">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <h2 class="bg-primary filter-titles ">Choose location and criteria</h2>

        <main-search-filter></main-search-filter>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a class="btn btn-primary filter-titles" href="#">Near you</a>

        <search-map></search-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to require the image.

1) Inside the hero component, you can add:

```
loadImage(image: string) {
    return require('../public/images/' + image);
}
```

Note: `../public/images` should point to the images container folder of your project.

2) The template:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + loadImage('1.jpg') + ')'}"
```

Comment: what about use `background-image` within css file?